# adaptIntegrate upper limit in R not working?

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I have a two-dimensional function that needs to be integrated from 0 to infinity for one of the variables:

```
library(cubature)

k = 0.5
m = 0.05

integrand = function(variables) {

    x = variables[1]
    r = variables[2]

    p = sqrt(x*(1 - x))*exp((-1/2)*(((k**2)*x*(1 - x)*(r**2)) + ((m**2)/((k**2)*x*(1 - x)))))
    d.p = -((x*(1 - x))**(3/2))*(k**2)*r*exp((-1/2)*(((k**2)*x*(1 - x)*(r**2)) + ((m**2)/((k**2)*x*(1 - x)))))

    return (2*pi*r*(1/(4*(x**2)*((1 - x)**2)))*(((x**2 + (1 - x)**2)*(d.p**2)) + (m*p)**2))

}
```

`adaptIntegrate`, however, does not work with `Inf` as an upper limit, so I tried integrating with a large number. The plot below from `r = 0` to `r = 45` suggested 45 would be a good upper limit.

[image]

However, the following code

```
adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 45))$integral
```

does not give me the expected result. As I increase the upper limit, the result decreases until it eventually gives 0.

I have tried using a large upper limit instead of `Inf` on other functions, and it seems to work no matter how high I make the upper limit. Is there a reason it is failing so much this time, and is there a way to properly integrate this function?

Comment: What is your desired result? The decreasing phenomena is quite common in numerical integration, because numerical integration is just evaluating function at some points chosen by certain algorithm, and use splines or something like that to approximate the whole function and calculate the integration of the approximation function, if the range is too large, the approximated function can contain negative values! and thus the integration is decreased.

Comment: Missing paren in the line beginning 'return'. Please test your code in the future.

Comment: @Consistency My desired result is 6.96. I don't believe my function goes negative anywhere; I increased the range on my plot and I don't see any negative values, just 0 as r increases and the negative exponent decreases. Thank you for the insight into the integration method, though!

Comment: @42- Oh, you're right. I've fixed it now, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wrapper to hcubature which makes it accept infinite limits:

```
hcubature.inf <- function() {
  cl <- match.call()
  cl[[1L]] <- quote(cubature::hcubature)
  if(all(is.finite(c(lowerLimit,upperLimit)))) return(eval.parent(cl))

  # convert to new coordinates to incorporate infinities                                                             
  cl[['upperLimit']] <- atan(upperLimit)
  cl[['lowerLimit']] <- atan(lowerLimit)
  # wrap the coordinate transformation                                                                               
  if(!vectorInterface) {
    newfun <- function(x,...) {
      z <- tan(x)
      jac <- rep(prod(1/cos(x))^2, fDim)
      f(z,...) * jac
    }
  } else {
    newfun <- function(x,...) {
      z <- tan(x)
      jac <- rep(apply(x,2,function(x) prod(1/cos(x)))^2, each=fDim)
      f(z,...) * jac
    }
  }
  cl[['f']] <- newfun
  eval.parent(cl)
}
formals(hcubature.inf) <- formals(hcubature)

hcubature.inf(integrand, c(0,0), c(1,Inf))$integral
[1] 6.450675
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears you have it on some authority that this polynomial function should stay positive. After supplying the missing parentheses and running some test cases, I suspect you have made an error in transcribing your expression into R.

```
> adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 45))$integral
[1] 6.3301
> adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, Inf))$integral
[1] NaN
> adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 300))$integral
[1] 6.4436
> adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 600))$integral
[1] 6.4436
> adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 6000))$integral
[1] 2.7391
# backing up a bit .......
> adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 3000))$integral
[1] 6.4495
```

<strike>It appears your integrand crosses zero some place between 3000 and 6000 on the y axis.</strike> Appears your function has a returned value of NaN at many of the points that are evaluated over the grid of integration. I increase with finite values and see that the result stays 0 over a wide range of values for the second limit. Numeric integration has some inherent limitations devolving from its finite nature:

```
> adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 1000000000))$integral
[1] 0
```

I believe that I have read that `adaptIntegrate` sometimes fails if the gradient of the results is too shallow. I seem to remember that the "adapt"-part of its name means it applies some heuristics to the search for a proper sectioning of the parameter space that depend on changes on the integrand value.

The `hcubature method is the default. The help page suggests that using`pcubature` will apply more stringent tests:

```
> hcubature(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0.00001, 0.1), upperLimit = c(.9999999,360))$integral
[1] 6.4489
> pcubature(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0.00001, 0.1), upperLimit = c(.9999999,360))$integral
[1] 6.4505                  # value increased with same arguments
```

I think you proposed upper limit is too timid based on this plot:

[image]

This is the best I've been able to do:

```
 pcubature(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0.0000000001, 0.000000001), 
                      upperLimit = c(.99999999999999, 360))$integral
[1] 6.4507
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is that since you cannot determine the proper upper-bound, you can do some mathematical transformation: change of variables to change the range from 0 to Inf to something like 0 to 1. The integral should be the same theoretically. For example,

```
library(cubature)

k = 0.5
m = 0.05

integrand = function(variables) {

    x = variables[1]
    r = variables[2]

    p = sqrt(x*(1 - x))*exp((-1/2)*(((k**2)*x*(1 - x)*(r**2)) + ((m**2)/((k**2)*x*(1 - x)))))
    d.p = -((x*(1 - x))**(3/2))*(k**2)*r*exp((-1/2)*(((k**2)*x*(1 - x)*(r**2)) + ((m**2)/((k**2)*x*(1 - x)))))

    return(2*pi*r*(1/(4*(x**2)*((1 - x)**2)))*(((x**2 + (1 - x)**2)*(d.p**2)) + (m*p)**2))

}

integrand1 <- function(variables){
    x <- variables[1]
    ## y is the variable from 0 to 1
    y <- variables[2]
    ## r is 0 to Inf by this transformation
    r <- y / (1 - y)
    ## the new function will be the original function times the Jacobian
    ## i.e. the derivative of r = y / (1 - y)
    integrand(c(x, r)) / (1 - y) ^ 2
}

## adaptIntegrate(integrand, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 45))$integral

adaptIntegrate(integrand1, lowerLimit = c(0, 0), upperLimit = c(1, 1))$integral
```

And the result I got is 6.450692, which is similar to 42-'s result, but not close to your desired result.